# Leetcode problem: Department Highest Salary

Tags: sql

The Employee table holds all employees. Every employee has an Id, a salary, and there is also a column for the department Id.

```
+----+-------+--------+--------------+
| Id | Name  | Salary | DepartmentId |
+----+-------+--------+--------------+
| 1  | Joe   | 70000  | 1            |
| 2  | Jim   | 90000  | 1            |
| 3  | Henry | 80000  | 2            |
| 4  | Sam   | 60000  | 2            |
| 5  | Max   | 90000  | 1            |
+----+-------+--------+--------------+
```

The Department table holds all departments of the company.

```
+----+----------+
| Id | Name     |
+----+----------+
| 1  | IT       |
| 2  | Sales    |
+----+----------+
```

Write a SQL query to find employees who have the highest salary in each of the departments. For the above tables, your SQL query should return the following rows (order of rows does not matter).

```
+------------+----------+--------+
| Department | Employee | Salary |
+------------+----------+--------+
| IT         | Max      | 90000  |
| IT         | Jim      | 90000  |
| Sales      | Henry    | 80000  |
+------------+----------+--------+
```

My solution is below, Someone please tell me why this is not working

```sql
Select Department , Employee ,MAX(Salary) AS SALARY FROM
(select Department.Name AS Department,Employee.Name as Employee, SALARY from employee
LEFT JOIN Department
ON Employee.DepartmentID=Department.ID) as base
GROUP BY Department
```

The difference between my code output and expected output is given below.

Output

```json
{"headers": ["Department", "Employee", "SALARY"], "values": [["IT", "Joe", 90000], ["Sales", "Henry", 80000]]}
```

Expected

```json
{"headers": ["Department", "Employee", "Salary"], "values": [["IT", "Jim", 90000], ["Sales", "Henry", 80000], ["IT", "Max", 90000]]}
```

Comment: how is it "not working"?

Comment: Output
{"headers": ["Department", "Employee", "SALARY"], "values": [["IT", "Joe", 90000], ["Sales", "Henry", 80000]]}
 Expected
{"headers": ["Department", "Employee", "Salary"], "values": [["IT", "Jim", 90000], ["Sales", "Henry", 80000], ["IT", "Max", 90000]]}

Comment: The difference between the expected output and my code output

Comment: Why do you have `Employee` in the SELECT but not in the `GROUP BY` clause? What do you expect would be returned?

Comment: Your query is malformed and should generate a syntax error.  The `SELECT` columns are not consistent with the `GROUP BY` columns.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: not sure what you mean, but not every field from select _has_ to be either in group by or an aggregate function: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dadd4b/1/0. It most likely _should be_, but it's not an error (at least, not in mysql)

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev . . . https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html.  Just because MySQL used to be "broken" in this respect does not mean that the query makes sense,.

Comment: WITH max_salary as(SELECT MAX(Salary) AS Salary FROM employee
GROUP BY DepartmentId)
SELECT department.name AS Department, employee.name 
AS Employee, employee.Salary
FROM employee JOIN  max_salary  ON employee.salary=max_salary.salary
JOIN 
Department ON  department.id = employee.DepartmentId 

This is what I have tried to do . it is giving the below output and expected result

Comment: Output
{"headers": ["Department", "Employee", "Salary"], "values": [["IT", "Joe", 60000], ["IT", "Joe", 60000], ["HR", "Max", 60000], ["HR", "Max", 60000]]}
Expected
{"headers":["Department","Employee","Salary"],"values":[["IT","Joe",60000],["HR","Max",60000]]}

Comment: @GordonLinoff: oh, this query doesn't make sense, no doubt.

Answer (score 0):

> Someone please tell me why this is not working

Because what you have so far reads like this: "for every department, return an unspecified employee, and also return max salary within this department". Note that max salary is in no way related to the employee that is returned. In this case, it's seems to be returning the first employee for each department. And in case of "Sales", it even turns out to be correct, accidentally.

What you should have written is "for every department, find out its max salary. Then find all employees whose salary is equal to max_salary for their department"

Comment: In line with what you have mentioned, '''  WITH max_salary as(SELECT MAX(Salary) AS Salary FROM employee GROUP BY DepartmentId) SELECT department.name AS Department, employee.name AS Employee, employee.Salary FROM employee JOIN max_salary ON employee.salary=max_salary.salary JOIN Department ON department.id = employee.DepartmentId''' Still the solution is not correct..

Comment: @shivanisingh: because it is not doing the same thing. My proposal: "find all employees whose salary is equal to max_salary for their department". This code, roughly: "find all employees whose salary is max salary in at least one department (not necessarily theirs)"

Answer (score 0):

You first need to get the MAX(SALARY) by Department and then query all employee that have this salary in this department.

```sql
-- max salary by department, adding DepartmentName to the result
WITH max_salary as ( 
    SELECT Department.DepartmentId, Department.Name as DptName, MAX(SALARY)
    FROM Employee JOIN Department
    ON Employee.DepartmentID=Department.ID
    GROUP BY DepartmentId, Name
)

-- select ALL employees with max salary
SELECT DptName, e.Name, e.SALARY
FROM Employee e JOIN max_salary m
ON e.SALARY=m.SALARY AND e.DepartmentId=m.DepartmentId
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the highest `SALARY` for each department, and then return the employees whose salaries are equal to the `maximum SALARY`. The following query does this.

```
WITH TB_Salary as ( 
    SELECT MAX(SALARY) AS Salary,DepartmentId
    FROM employee
    GROUP BY DepartmentId
)
SELECT DISTINCT Department.Name AS Department,employee.Name AS Employee,employee.Salary FROM employee
JOIN TB_Salary ON employee.SALARY = TB_Salary.SALARY AND employee.DepartmentId = TB_Salary.DepartmentId
JOIN Department ON Department.Id = employee.DepartmentId
ORDER BY employee.Salary DESC
```

OR

```
SELECT DISTINCT Department.Name AS Department,employee.Name AS Employee,employee.Salary 
FROM employee
JOIN 
 ( 
    SELECT MAX(SALARY) AS Salary,DepartmentId
    FROM employee
    GROUP BY DepartmentId
) TB_Salary
ON employee.SALARY = TB_Salary.SALARY AND employee.DepartmentId = TB_Salary.DepartmentId
JOIN Department ON Department.Id = employee.DepartmentId
ORDER BY employee.Salary DESC
```

output:

[image]

Comment: In your first query shouldn't you add DepartmentId in the select (inside the CTE), since you group by this field?
Also you should join on max salary AND department

Comment: No, I first get the maximum Salary for each department (80,000 and 90,000). Employees whose salaries are equal to these amounts are then returned.

Comment: But if there is a John working in IT with a SALARY of 80,000 he will be returned.

Comment: @politinsa Yes, it will be returned if it is available as a record.

Comment: By the 1st query , the solution is not getting accepted as the following variation in output Output
{"headers": ["Department", "Employee", "Salary"], "values": [["IT", "Joe", 60000], ["IT", "Joe", 60000], ["HR", "Max", 60000], ["HR", "Max", 60000]]}
Expected
{"headers":["Department","Employee","Salary"],"values":[["IT","Joe",60000],["HR","Max",60000]]} Any suggestions please?

Comment: You can use DISTINCT I corrected the answer.

Comment: @politinsa I had forgotten a point. I changed it. The code now works perfectly.

Comment: @meysamasadi now your code is exactly like the one I presented in my answer but OP does not seem to test one

Comment: @politinsa No, my query different from yours. My query first returns the maximum salary of each department with its ID and then returns the salaries equal to the maximum salary in each department. My query is absolutely correct.

Comment: @politinsa You have used join within cte. But my query also did nothing.